# Gulp task watcher finds tests on first pass, but not subsequent executions

Tags: gulp, mocha.js

Having a strange behavior in a gulp task. I have one task that runs my tests just fine every time I manually run it:

```
gulp.task('run-tests', function () {
  return gulp.src('./test/**/*.js', { read: false })
    .pipe(mocha({ reporter: 'spec' }));
});
```

So then I setup a watcher to auto run them when any of the source or tests run:

```
gulp.task('watch-tests', function () {
  gulp.watch(['./generators/**', './test/**/*.js'], ['run-tests']);
});
```

The first problem is that the tests aren't run when the task starts... I'd like for a first pass when I start this up.

But the bigger issue is that when once I do get the watcher to fire by updating a file, it correctly executes all my tests, but in every subsequent time, it doesn't find any of my tests... as you can see from the following output. Any ideas? Very strange...

```
 $ gulp watch-tests
[16:55:15] Using gulpfile ~/repos/../gulpfile.js
[16:55:15] Starting 'watch-tests'...
[16:55:15] Finished 'watch-tests' after 14 ms
[16:55:19] Starting 'run-tests'...

  app
    server.js
      ✓ creates server.js in src/server
      ✓ set port number in server.js
    package.json
      ✓ creates package.json in root
      ✓ sets correct values in package.json
    static files created in src/public
      ✓ created public/index.html
      ✓ created public/content/site.css

  6 passing (75ms)

[16:55:20] Finished 'run-tests' after 805 ms
[16:55:38] Starting 'run-tests'...

  0 passing (0ms)

[16:55:38] Finished 'run-tests' after 4.14 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that somewhere in your code (tests or the actual code under test) the current working directory gets changed, and the next run of tests doesn't find the specified test files anymore. You cannot see this from the code in your question, I found it in the github [generator-office](https://github.com/andrewconnell/generator-office) project you link to in a comment.

You can check this by inserting

```
console.log(process.cwd());
```

into your test task and see it change on the second run.

Now you could rewrite your code to not change the current working directory or always reset it, but you can also fix it in your gulpfile by creating a variable to save the CWD to (outside if the task definition).

```
var currentWorkingDirectory = process.cwd();
```

And then change the file specification from

```
gulp.src('test/*.js')
```

to

```
gulp.src(currentWorkingDirectory + '/test/*.js')
```

in your test task. (the watch task is not affected by the change in working directory, probably because it will get the references to the files at startup and not scan them again)

Comment: I'm confused tho... When I run mocha directly with the -w flag, it works just fine. So if it was changing why wouldn't it affect mocha and only affect gulp?

Comment: The gulp.src command depends on the CWD and evaluates the src on every run, maybe mocha -w behaves differently - it could either store the CWD at startup (as I suggest you do for gulp as well) or have some means for setting/resetting the CWD.

Comment: That fixed it... I grab the CWD outside of all gulp tasks, then add it to the path to the files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is super annoying,

but simply remove the "./" from the watcher path, like this:

```
gulp.task('watch-tests', function () {
    gulp.watch(['generators/**', 'test/**/*.js'], ['run-tests']);
});
```

make sure the paths work with out the "./" and it will work as many times as you want.

Comment: I had tried that and still get the exact same results... zero tests run after the first pass though.

Comment: which version of gulp are you? I use 3.9.0 and both with "./" and without works again and again, copy pasted your code.

Comment: I'm running 3.9.0 as well & same result... first pass runs all tests, second nothing :(

Comment: mmmm can you show the file structure, send the code.... something, all my tests run perfectly with what I said

Comment: Sure... it's this repo: https://github.com/andrewconnell/generator-office

I have commented out lines 16-19, 22 & 24 to isolate it to just my tests. What's missing is the watch task (that isn't committed because I can't get it working, but easy to tweak). This is the exact project that's triggered this thread.

I think the only dependency you'll have is to possibly install Yeoman globally (if the slim chance you don't already have it)